# RefineryCms engine generation with resource type wrong generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I'm a beginner with RefineryCMS and Rails. I made my RefineryCMS app and I'm trying to generate my engine, as described in the guides. 
I'm running this command:

```
rails g refinery:engine article title:string reference:string file:resource
```

In the view I get in the Admin part there is no button to browse or anything as expected for the file resource, just a single box to introduce text. This is part of the form partial:

```
  <div class='field'>
    <%= f.label :file_id -%>
    <%= f.text_field :file_id -%>
  </div>
```

I had to change the gemspec file in the engine as mentioned [RefineryCMS Engines Error: did not have a valid gemspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552152/refinerycms-engines-error-did-not-have-a-valid-gemspec)

this is part of my gemfile:

```
ruby '2.1.1'
gem 'rails', '3.2.17'
gem 'pg'
# Refinery CMS
gem 'refinerycms', '~> 2.1.0'

# Optionally, specify additional Refinery CMS Extensions here:
gem 'refinerycms-acts-as-indexed', '~> 1.0.0'

# Refinery's news engine allows you to post updates to the news section of your website.
gem 'refinerycms-news', '~> 2.1.0'
gem 'refinerycms-articles', :path => 'vendor/extensions'
```

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.

So is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong? How do I get a button to browse the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've figured out how to solve this, thanks to this other quetion: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481

The problem is the generator doesn't create right views and model. You'll have to do this modifications by hand.

First in the view **_form.html.erb:**

```
<div class='field'>
    <%= f.label :file_id -%>
    <%= render :partial => "/refinery/admin/resource_picker", :locals =>
    {
          :f => f,
          :field => :file_id,
          :resource => @article.file} %>
</div>
```

And now add this line to the model, **article.rb**:

```
belongs_to :file, :class_name=>'Resource'
```

Of course you have to modify the show view too. For example:

```
  <section>
    <h1>File</h1>
    <p>
      <%= link_to("Download", @article.file.url) if @article.file %>
    </p>
  </section>
```

Would be nice if the generator would do this all automatically but with this you'll have it working.